# how to use SwiftyJSON framework to read a locally declared JSON

Tags: json, swift3, swifty-json

I am trying to read a locally declared JSON, since I still do not have the network ready to send me JSON examples for the app we are developing.
For some reason I get a null when trying to print the json created by SwiftyJSON framework.
This is my class:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
let mockShifts = "{\"numOfShiftsInDay\": 3,\"shifts\": [{\"StartTime\": \"06:30\",\"EndTime\": \"14:00\"},{\"StartTime\": \"14:00\",\"EndTime\": \"19:00},{\"StartTime\": \"19:00\",\"EndTime\":\"01:00\"}]}"
class WeeklySchedule {

var shifts: [Shift] = []
var shiftsAmount: Int = 3
var relative: Int = 0
func setShiftsAmount(amount: Int){
    self.shiftsAmount = amount
    for _ in 1...amount{
        self.shifts.append(Shift())
    }
    getShifts()
}

func getRelative() -> Int{
    return relative
}
func getShifts(){
    let data = mockShifts.data(using: .utf8)!
    let json = JSON(data: data)
    print(mockShifts) //This prints out a JSON that looks OK to me
    print(json)       //This prints NULL
    if let numOfShifts = json["numOfShiftsInDay"].string {
        print(numOfShifts) //This code is unreachable
    }
}
}
```

And this is my console output, when calling `setShiftsAmount()` which calls `getShifts()`:

> {"numOfShiftsInDay": 3,"shifts": [{"StartTime": "06:30","EndTime": "14:00"},{"StartTime": "14:00","EndTime": "19:00},{"StartTime": "19:00","EndTime":"01:00"}]}
>
> null

Why is my JSON null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting null for your `JSON` because your `JSON` string `mockShifts` is not contain's valid `JSON`, there is missing `double quote(\")` for the `EndTime` key after `19:00` in the second object of array shifts. Add that double quote and you all set to go.

```
let mockShifts = "{\"numOfShiftsInDay\": 3,\"shifts\": [{\"StartTime\": \"06:30\",\"EndTime\": \"14:00\"},{\"StartTime\": \"14:00\",\"EndTime\": \"19:00\"},{\"StartTime\": \"19:00\",\"EndTime\":\"01:00\"}]}"
```

Comment: This is correct. I feel embarrassed!! I will accept this once SO lets me (few minutes)

Comment: @Sharonica Welcome mate :) It happens some time that mistake is too small.